# why my login screen is not working

Tags: android, authentication

I have a created a screen for which it will ask the password and compare with the inbuilt password and launch another screen but I am unable to launch the activity even if I give the correct password. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     public static String lock = "vamsi";
     public static String locker;
     EditText et;
     Button b;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         locker = et.getText().toString();

         b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     if (locker.equals(lock)) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent("screen");

                     startActivity(intent);
                 }
             }
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of screen here: 

 Intent intent=new Intent("screen"); And please mention here the name of current Activity and that Activity which you want to Open.

Comment: please work around before asking questions here.

Comment: ya i did it's not working , so only i asked @Goofy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write Following line

```
Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), FileName.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent("screen");
```

Where **FileName** is the name of that activity which do you want to open in Onclick Method.

Comment: ya i solved the problem but why i should i keep converting string in the onclicklistener activity ? will all the code present in the oncreate function execute or not ?

Comment: Because When you keep the code in Onclick method then it check string dynamically but when you keep the code in onCreate then it check the String only at once time when Activity start.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are new bee here, so before going to start developing you have to read some theory plus go through with some tutorial. as per you code I assume you don't know how to call `intent`.

Look here, what is [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)?

your onclick code should like below:

```
         b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               locker = et.getText().toString();
                 if (locker.equalsIgnoreCase(lock)) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),example.class);
               //example.class is the name of activity which you want to launch.
              startActivity(intent);
                 }

             }

         });
```

Comment: ya i solved the problem but why i should i keep converting string in the onclicklistener activity ? will all the code present in the oncreate function execute or not ?

Comment: @user1395129 its also fine but its better if your keep inside onclick becoz whenever you click it fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would like to add some points here:

1. use Async task if you are using Web services.
2. please work around before asking here.

probably you can try this :

```
if(locker.contains(lock)){
             Intent success = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,MainMenu.class);
             startActivity(success
}else{

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginScreen.this);
builder.setMessage("Incorrect LoginId or Password");
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
builder.create().show();
}
```

Comment: ya i solved the problem but why i should i keep converting string in the onclicklistener activity ? will all the code present in the oncreate function execute or not ?